# How to repopulate user entered form values in angular JS when the REST API call fails

Tags: angularjs, rest, api

I am having an angular js form with dropdowns and text boxes ,on submitting the form I am planning to call an REST API to save the user entered values. i Would like to know if in case the insert fails, how to re populate the user entered form values in  the frontend with an error message

Comment: please add what you have so far.

Comment: Right now, what i have done is created an angular js app that would do a rest api call, which would inturn return a success / failure message . If failure it would return a error message. I am planning to show the error message on the screen and retain the form values whatever use has submitted.this is where i am stuck now

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could go about making a copy and re-setting the user deets on. Hope it helps. Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tlombrana22/pen/rWwNgv?editors=1010) for the below code.

```js
function exampleFactory($http) {
  //placeholder exampleFactory 
  console.log('exampleFactory');

  function login() {
    return {
      data: console.log('data saved')
    };
  }
  return {
    login: login
  };
}

function exampleController($scope, exampleFactory, $timeout) {
  var copyOfUserDeets;
  $scope.userForm = {};
  $scope.submit = function(userDeets) {
    copyOfUserDeets = angular.copy(userDeets);
    $scope.userForm = {};
    // exampleFactory
    //     .login(userDeets)
    //     .then(function(resp) {
    //         $scope.userForm = {};
    //     })
    //     .catch(function(error) {
    //         $scope.userForm = copyOfUserDeets;
    //     });
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.userForm = copyOfUserDeets;
    }, 10000);
  };
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController)
  .factory('exampleFactory', exampleFactory);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid text-center" ng-app="app">
  <div class="container text-center" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <form name="userLoginForm" ng-submit="submit(userForm)" ng-model="userForm" novalidate>
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="userForm.email" required="">
      <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="userForm.text" required="">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="userLoginForm.$invalid">
    </form>
    <pre>{{userForm}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```